# complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^{n+2}$ as K3 surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, k3-surfaces

I am reading D. Huybrechts' lecture "Lectures on K3 surfaces", http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/K3Global.pdf
He claims that a smooth complete intersection of type $(d_1,\cdots, d_n)$ in $\mathbb P^{n+2}$ is a K3 surface if and only if $\sum {d_i} = n + 3$.

What confuses me is that he then says **under the natural assumption that all $d_{i}>1$** there are in fact only three cases (up to permutation):

(a) $n=1, d_1=4$.

(b)$n=2, d_1=2, d_2=3$.

(c)$n=3, d_1=d_2=d_3=2.$

**I wonder why we asssme $d_i>1$? What will happen if some $d_i=1$?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, say, $d_1 = 1$ this complete intersection is equal to a complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ of type $(d_2,\dots,d_n)$, so there is no sense in considering it separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, do you mean the hypersurface  of degree 1 in $\mathbb P^{n+1}$ equal to $\mathbb P^n$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Thanks for your help.